# django import-export: unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make django's export/import work ( django-import-export.readthedocs.org )

Problem is that it wants "id" in every file header to identify it. I added before_import function but it gives me following error:

```
TypeError("before_import() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file_name'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 340, in import_data
self.before_import(dataset, real_dry_run, **kwargs)
TypeError: before_import() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file_name'
```

**Here is code from admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
# Register your models here.
from import_export import resources
from import_export import fields
from keywords.models import Book
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def before_import(self, dataset, dry_run):

        if dataset.headers:
            dataset.headers = [str(header).lower().strip() for header in dataset.headers]
        if 'id' not in dataset.headers:
            dataset.headers.append('id')    

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'price',)



class BookAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = BookResource
    pass




admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the docs would show that your method signature is wrong...

From [the docs](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_resources.html?highlight=before_import#import_export.resources.Resource.before_import)

```
before_import(dataset, dry_run, **kwargs)
```

Your code looks like it should be

```
def before_import(self, dataset, dry_run, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Note: You may actually need to use the filename kwarg anyway. I've never used this module

Comment: Thank this solved first issue, now this function doesn't give error anymore but it still doesn't work :/

I tried putting it everywhere in admin.py file, even in resources.py (from import-export app) and can't get it to append this ID